# Wordpress post image (details) default class

Tags: css, image, wordpress, class, post

I want to set a default class for all images in a single post eg. they have a red border. How do i do that? Something like on http://net.tutsplus.com

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the div containing the post an id attribute equal to the id of the post and use

```
#post-[id] img { border:1px solid red; }
```

Comment: That will only work for that specific post. It will not work for all posts. If you want to use it for all psots, then maybe add a div container that wraps the post and give that an ID.

Answer (score 0):

There's a filter named `get_image_tag_class` that should give you the access you need if you're using built in functionality to place images.